# Handle mutiple UDP client

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, serversocket, tcplistener

I have a single server and multiple UDP clients in my setup and each sending a boolean string (true/false 5 byte max) at regular intervals of time (few milliseconds). Based on which i am determining if the device is alive or not.The number of clients are unknown before starting the program and using c++ as my programming language.

1. Is it possible to have a multi threading in UDP socket connection ? I came across and example for TCP where they create a new socket descriptor and spawn a thread. If its possible to write a multi threading for UDP serves please provide example/reference code.
2. During

```
while (true) 
{
    if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,
        (struct sockaddr *)&cient_addr, &client_addr_len)) == -1)
    {
        perror("recvfrom");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Process buffer...  
    // Do something with buffer 
}
```

In multiple client scenario if i receive message from one client its copied to local buffer of maximum buffer size. And while process this message if we receive one more message from another client where will this message store intermittently before reading to local buffer ? Does the socket file descriptor has its own buffer ?

3. What happens if both clients send message at the same time ? Only one is read to local buffer what will happen to another message ? will it wait for the next recvfrom ?
4. I read that if Maximum buffer is less that the message / packet size received then the recvfrom will only read the max buffer length and might through some error...Although all of my client only send 5 bytes maximum..If I assign Maximum bytes to 1024 bytes which is way far than expected what prices am I gonna pay ?

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Using multi-threading with UDP is not a 1:1 like it is in TCP. It can be done, but is generally not needed. 2. yes, a socket has internal buffering, but UDP does not guarantee delivery, so if the buffer fills up if you read too slowly, subsequent messages will be discarded. 3. yes, subsequent messages are buffered and will be returned by later calls to `recvfrom()`. 4. yes, UDP can truncate message data. The error code from `recvfrom()` will tell you when that happens.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is it possible to observer if socket internal buffer if overflown or not ? Can you also comment on Effect of using Maximum buffer of 1024 bytes in recvfrom() function although I am sure that each packets are of 5 bytes max... Is it just have extra program memory   (1024 bytes = 1kB) of 1 kB.

Comment: messages are discarded silently, there is no way to know when they are. But you can increase the internal buffer size via `setsockopt()` if needed. Using a memory buffer of 1024 bytes to receive 5-byte messages is way overkill and is just wasted memory. And has nothing to do with the internal buffer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau..Thanks. You mean to say that, just  for design purpose there is no way we can monitor/observer how much of the socket internal buffer is actively filled during the server execution ?

Comment: No, there is no API to monitor the internal buffer. For TCP, you can use `ioctlsocket(FIOREAD)` to know how many bytes are currently in the internal buffer, but for UDP that only returns the size of the 1st queued message, not the total of all queued messages.